# Date comparison - How to check if 20 minutes have passed?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How to check if 20 minutes have passed from current date?

For example:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var oldDate = "08/10/2011 23:50:31"; 

    if(start ??) {
     //20 minutes were passed from start
    }
```

what's the best way to do this?
Thanks :)

Comment: You might want to use `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now` to avoid issues with daylight savings time changes when the clock can leap back or forward.

Comment: @Hightechrider: Using `UtcNow` is only useful if the comparison timestamp is in UTC!

Comment: @Gabe, obviously yes, but converting the start time to UTC and comparing it is going to be better than comparing to `DateTime.Now` because otherwise you can get situations where an hour appears to have elapsed when it hasn't!

Answer (score 112, accepted):

1. You should convert your start time to a UTC time, say 'start'.
2. You can now compare your start time to the current UTC time using:

   `DateTime.UtcNow > start.AddMinutes(20)`

This approach means that you will get the correct answer around daylight savings time changes.

By adding time to the start time instead of subtracting and comparing the total time on a TimeSpan you have a more readable syntax AND you can handle more date difference cases, e.g. 1 month from the start, 2 weeks from the start, ...

Comment: +1 for teaching something which is logical but was not self-evident to me. And I also like the hint about the more readable syntax.

Comment: looks like the best way,I'II try this.

Comment: Does this change the actual object. e.g. if you store this somewhere in memory, will it permanently be incremented by 20 minutes?

In that case it would make way more sense to remove 20 minutes from DateTime.UtcNow since that's a constructor

Comment: @MathijsSegers MSDN: *This method does not change the value of this DateTime.*

Comment: umm, shouldn't it be: start.AddMinutes(20) < DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: @solujic You are correct, the title of the question is the other way round, I will fix

Answer (score 28):

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var oldDate = DateTime.Parse("08/10/2011 23:50:31");

if ((start - oldDate).TotalMinutes >= 20)
{
    //20 minutes were passed from start  
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the hour is passed. 
for start = `23:20` end = `24:20` it's true.

Comment: ¿Why would you send 24:20 as the time? In such case, you should use a TimeSpan object, not a DateTime, DateTime objects are meant to be used for valid time representations, not "24:20"

Answer (score 7):

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
var oldDate = DateTime.Parse("08/10/2011 23:50:31"); 

    if(start.Subtract(oldDate) >= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)) 
    {
     //20 minutes were passed from start
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Parse `oldDate` into a `DateTime` object (`DateTime.Parse`).

Subtract the parsed date from `start`. This will return a `TimeSpan`.

Inspect `TotalMinutes`.

Comment: +1 this answer is better than mine.  I forgot about TotalMinutes...this answer prevents an unnecessary second TimeSpan.

Comment: Personally I prefer `start.AddMinutes(20) > now` because it says "more than 20 minutes have elapsed since the start".  Also, you can use it to test for intervals measured in weeks, months, years which you cannot easily do with a TimeSpan.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by using a JodaTime Library in my project. I came out with this code.

```
String datetime1 = "2012/08/24 05:22:34";
String datetime2 = "2012/08/24 05:23:28";

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime time1 = format.parseDateTime(datetime1);
DateTime time2 = format.parseDateTime(datetime2);
Minutes Interval = Minutes.minutesBetween(time1, time2);
Minutes minInterval = Minutes.minutes(20);

if(Interval.isGreaterThan(minInterval)){
  return true;
}
else{
  return false;
}
```

This will check if the Time Interval between datetime1 and datetime2 is GreaterThan 20 Minutes. Change the property to Seconds. It will be easier for you know. This will return false.

Comment: I know i am very late (juste incase someone sees it nowadays) but you can now use TimeSpan to accomplish that like : TimeSpan ts = date2 - date1; and then have the result in ts.TotalMinutes

Answer (score 0):

```
var end = DateTime.Parse(oldDate);   
 if (start.Hour == end.Hour && start.AddMinutes(20).Minute >= end.Minute)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the hour is passed. 
for start = `23:20` end = `24:20` it's true.